# How to write pointcut with customized annotation to print the global variable value that used in a function?

Tags: scala, annotations, aspectj, aspect, pointcut

I'm trying to log all the variables that method used to calculate something but I don't know how can I access to the specific global variables that method used:

```
  @BuAnnotation(funcName = "foo", category = BuAnnotation.Category.BU)
  @Scores(scoreName = "globalScoreVariableValue", category = Scores.Category.SC)
  def Boolean foo = {
    val globalScoreVariableValue = b.globalScoreVariable.value
    val checkValue = globalScoreVariableValue > 2
    if (checkValue)
    {
      false
    }
    checkValue
  }
```

But I'm not sure how to handle the pointcut, since I tried many ways to write the retrieve it and the code doesn't reach it...

is there anyway to make it happen?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry if my question seems silly, but which language is that? You tagged your question _java_ but this does not look like Java to me. Furthermore, please provide a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) consisting of full classes and aspect code, something everybody can compile and run. Then maybe someone can help you.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your comment
After some investigating I figured out that unfortunately, local variables are not exposed via joinpoints. This means that we cannot write a pointcut to match them. However I tried some ways.. So we cannot do this directly.

Comment: Would you mind answering the question anyway? Which language? The _java_ tag is wrong. And as for local variables, that would have become visible if you had followed my advice to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I could have told you. So please don't ignore advice given by experienced users, they only want to guide you to get better help.

Comment: Sure, fixed it - thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

After some investigating I figured out that unfortunately, local variables are not exposed via joinpoints. This means that we cannot write a pointcut to match them. However I tried some ways.. So we cannot do this directly.
But, the simplest way is to refactor our code (not the method signature) 
I just create a function which get variable and return it as is, so I annotated the function and just call it where I use these variables.
Conceptually, this kind of refactoring might be better for our code.

```
    @BuAnnotation(funcName = "foo", category = BuAnnotation.Category.BU)
      def Boolean foo = {
        val globalScoreVariableValue = b.globalScoreVariable.value
        Logging.log(globalScoreVariableValue)

        val checkValue = globalScoreVariableValue > 2
        if (checkValue)
        {
          false
        }
        checkValue
    }

@CustomizedAnn
def log(v: Any): Any = v
```

Comment: I don't get it. The new code snippet still defines a local variable. What is different from your first approach? Please edit this answer and turn it into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), complete with application code, aspect code and helper/annotation classes (if any). This answer does not help others with the same problem, despite your description in prose (which is unclear, unfortunately). Just give your posts here - both questions and answers - a little more love. :-)